# Listen for `mousedown` on parent but let `click` to pass to children

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a `div` that listens for `mousedown` event. The `div` has some child buttons (absolutely positioned outside the `div`). I want to be able to click these buttons. But when I press the mouse button, the parent `div` intercepts the `mousedown` event. I can test the `.target` member to ignore the event if it happened on the buttons, but it seems that I never get the `click` event on these buttons this way.

Is there a way to solve this without adding yet another ancestor `div`?

Comment: Can you put the code up on https://jsfiddle.net/.  This might help people respond and get a clear picture of what's going on.  Also what browser are you using and is this expected to work on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target == this`

Example :

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <style>
           div {
               width: 100px;
               background-color: yellow;
               height: 100px;
           }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="d">I am div
            <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var divMousedown = document.getElementById("d");
            var Child = document.getElementById("btn1");
            divMousedown.onmousedown = function(event) {
                if(event.target == this)
                alert("You Mouse down on Div");
            }
            Child.onclick = function(event){
                if(event.target == this)
                    alert("You Click on Button")
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```